# Is there a systematic way to find the center of a finitely-presented, finite $p$ group?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, p-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Given a finitely-presented and finite $p$-group $G = \langle S \mid R \rangle$, is there a systematic way to find its center? My end goal is to find a subnormal chain of every order $1, p, p^2, \dots, p^n$ by iteratively quotienting $G/H$ where $H \leq Z(G)$ is of order $p$. And by looking at its preimage I should yield a normal subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$ and so on. Is there a systematic/algorithmic way to find $Z(G)$ just given a $p$-group's presentation? For instance, given the $3$-group of order $3^5$:

$$G = \langle a, b, c \mid [b, a]=a^{3^3} = c, b^3=c^3=1\rangle$$

Comment: Of course there is. It is difficult in general to compute with finite presentations, but since you know that this is a $p$-group, you should start by running the $p$-quotient algorithm, to convert it to a power-commutator presentation. That will immediately give you the lower exponent $p$ central series (which also gives the subnormal series you are looking for). Finding the center can then be done by finding it in successively larger quotients in the central series, where the inductive steps reduce to linear algebra.

Comment: I just did the calcualtion for your presentation in Magma, by running $\mathtt{pQuotient}$ first, and the centre has order $3^3$. I expect someone will demonstrate how to do it in GAP.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks a lot for this! And that checks out--I just ran GAP's `Centre` on the group and it came back as cyclic of order 27.